# How to avoid the eclipse debugger to stop in SpringApplicationBuilder.run

Tags: spring, eclipse, debugging

Every time I run a Spring application, the eclipse debugger stops during the startup in `SpringApplicationBuilder.run()`. I don't know why it stops there -- I didn't put a breakpoint there, and it slows the start of the application unnecessarily.

Is there a way to disable this annoying behavior of eclipse?

Comment: did you try to delete the debug configurations ??

Comment: @MohamedNabli I started with an empty configuration. Also my coworkers do experience the same issue, and we don't share the eclipse configuration with our source code.

Comment: Which `dev-tools` version are you using?

Comment: @JuzerAli There is `spring-boot-devtools` with version `1.5.8.RELEASE` included.

Comment: I remember seeing this problem. Either updating the dev-tools or the version of STS/Eclipse solved it for me. Don't remember exactly which.